# How can I add a button in Mapbox to toggle the measure tool on and off?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using this Mapbox example for creating a measuring tool.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/

However, I want to have a small icon button that toggles the tool on and off. I don't always need to measure distances. Much like the polygon draw example here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any direction would be great here. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I took a better look at the mapbox draw documentation and saw that it supports length as well. This meant I was simply able to switch out the area.